# Determining which items have been bought together (Jaccard coefficient)

Tags: mysql, sql

I've ran into an data related problem which I can't figure out. I think it is simplest to give some example data and the expected output, to clarify my problem.

I'm trying to calculate the [Jaccard coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) using purchase history. For this I need to find the products that were bought together and how many times this was.

I've got the following data to do so:

- category_id
- item_id
- user_id

The category_id and item_id together make a product uniquely identifiable. I attached a query below to a SQL-export with some sample data. With the following data:

- User A: purchased items 1-1, 2-2 and 1-3
- User B: purchased items 2-2, 1-3, 2-4 and 3-6
- User C: purchased items 1-1, 2-2 and 1-5

The desired result would be:

```
i1.cat_id : i1.item_id : i2.cat_id : i2:item_id : count
    1     :     1      :      2    :      2     :   2
    1     :     1      :      1    :      3     :   1
    1     :     1      :      1    :      5     :   1
    2     :     2      :      1    :      3     :   2
    2     :     2      :      2    :      4     :   1
    2     :     2      :      3    :      6     :   1
```

Recurrence where the items are reversed isn't a problem, it might even be desired.

**Example data**

```
CREATE TABLE `test_020516_01` (
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `visit_id` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `test_020516_01` (`cat_id`, `item_id`, `visit_id`) VALUES
(1, 1,  'A'),
(2, 2,  'A'),
(1, 3,  'A'),
(2, 2,  'B'),
(1, 3,  'B'),
(2, 4,  'B'),
(3, 6,  'B'),
(1, 1,  'C'),
(2, 2,  'C'),
(1, 5,  'C');
```

The following has been my best try, but it hasn't payed off. The count amounts to 4 for some combinations, which can never be more then 3 in this case.

```
SELECT STAT.cat_id, STAT.item_id, STAT1.cat_id, STAT1.item_id, COUNT(*)
FROM test_020516_01 STAT
JOIN (
    SELECT
        cat_id, item_id, visit_id AS visit, count(*) AS count
    FROM
        test_020516_01
    WHERE
        cat_id != 0
    AND
        visit_id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
        cat_id, item_id, visit_id
    ORDER BY
        count DESC
) STAT1
ON STAT.cat_id != STAT1.cat_id
AND STAT.item_id != STAT1.item_id
AND visit_id != STAT1.visit
GROUP BY
    STAT.cat_id, STAT.item_id, STAT1.cat_id, STAT1.item_id;
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't understand why you're summarising results as STAT1, or exactly what is it that you're after, but perhaps the following query will point you in the right direction (since its results match your expected results, although it includes some combinations that you left out, I couldn't say if for brevity or because some requirement that I didn't understand):

```
# non-permutable couples within same visitor
SELECT i1.cat_id, i1.item_id, i2.cat_id, i2.item_id, COUNT(*)
FROM test_020516_01 i1
JOIN test_020516_01 i2 ON (i2.visit_id = i1.visit_id AND 
                           CONCAT(i1.cat_id, ';', i1.item_id) < CONCAT(i2.cat_id, ';', i2.item_id))
GROUP BY i1.cat_id, i1.item_id, i2.cat_id, i2.item_id
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```